# Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]

Tags: spring

We are using Spring 3.0.5 and CXF 2.7.5. 
I am writing JMock to mock the data and test it locally. I am initialzing variables from spring config (appContext.xml) where the entries are like this:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" /> 
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
```

My Junit class has the code:

```
applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]
    {"/spring/applicationContext.xml"});
```

While running the JUnit test file, i am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'producerClient': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser$JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/WSDLException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.amfam.api.producer.web.controller.test.ProducerControllerTest.setUp(ProducerControllerTest.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'producerClient': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser$JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/WSDLException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1013)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:783)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:713)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:260)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1125)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContextResourceResolver.resolve(BusApplicationContextResourceResolver.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.resource.DefaultResourceManager.findResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.resource.DefaultResourceManager.resolveResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.resolveResource(ResourceInjector.java:442)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.visitMethod(ResourceInjector.java:229)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.annotation.AnnotationProcessor.processMethods(AnnotationProcessor.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.annotation.AnnotationProcessor.accept(AnnotationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:112)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.loadAndRegister(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.getBeansOfType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:305)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBeanLocator.getBeansOfType(SpringBeanLocator.java:145)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.CXFBusLifeCycleManager.initComplete(CXFBusLifeCycleManager.java:80)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl.initialize(CXFBusImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.setApplicationContext(SpringBus.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser$JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/WSDLException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/WSDLException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientFactoryBean.<init>(JaxWsClientFactoryBean.java:38)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.<init>(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser$JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean.<init>(JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 65 more
```

I am struck up at this stage and not able to proceed further..

Answer (score 5):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/WSDLException
```

This is your problem. You need to add javax.wsdl API classes to your test class path.

For example wsdl4j contains the class, so if you're using maven, try

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you don't use maven, you can download the jar from [this link](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=wsdl4j/wsdl4j/1.6.3/wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar).

Comment: Hi After copying wsdl.jar file, it works fine. I am getting another error.

Comment: @user2660389 if this solved the error in this question, you should accept this answer and if you still need help, open a thread for that other error (or search for it)

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'producer': Cannot create inner bean 'producerjsonProvider' of type [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider] while setting bean property 'providers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'producerjsonProvider' defined in class path resource [spring/serviceContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jettison/mapped/TypeConverter

Comment: @user2660389 this means you have a similar issue of missing libraries. This time you're missing jettison library. You can search for missing libraries [like this](http://mavenhub.com/c/org/codehaus/jettison/mapped/typeconverter/jar)